# How do I get info from a table with data from another table?

Tags: database, laravel, controller, laravel-blade, laravel-controller

I have a from group row with a dropdown that automatically fills with data form the table "clients".

```
<label for="client" class="text-muted font-weight-light text-center">{{ __('Client') }}</label>
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
       <select class="form-control" id="user" name="user">
       @foreach($clients as $client)
         <option value="{{$client->id}}">{{$client->firstname}} {{$client->lastname}} - {{$client->residence}} ({{$client->housing}} {{$client->housenr}})</option>
       @endforeach
       </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

this POST form pushes a whole form to a table named "tasks". Now the problem is that I'm using in this blade (for example) `{{$client->residence}}`, but I need to be able to do that in my controller in my insert function to push it to the database.

```
/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function insert(Request $request)
{
    $clients = Clients::All();

    $id = auth()->user()->id;
    $title = $request->input('title');
    $startdate = $request->input('startdate');
    $enddate = $request->input('enddate');
    $starttime = $request->input('starttime');
    $endtime = $request->input('endtime');
    $description = $request->input('description');

    $data=array(
        "uuid"=>$id,
        "title"=>$title,
        "client"=>$client,
        "startdate"=>$startdate,
        "enddate"=>$enddate,
        "starttime"=>$starttime,
        "endtime"=>$endtime,
        "description"=>$description);
    DB::table('tasks')->insert($data);
    return redirect('/todo');
}
```

So what I would like to do is use the selected `{{$client->id}}` to get the information to push it to the task table in separate columns.

Hopefully it is clear what I mean.

Comment: What is the problem? You have the client_id, you can simply search for the client by its id and then find the client.

Comment: I fixed it already but im struggling with a conversion.

Comment: What is included in the request that you are receiving? insert a dd($request); in insert and show us the output

Answer (score 0):

So I alreasy found the solution, just using queries solved my problem. now the only problem I'm facing now is that with `$firstname = DB::select('select firstname from clients where id='.$clientid);`

I'm getting an array but for the export to the table im also using an array and I cant pass the $firstname array within the $data Array

```
$data=array(
        "uuid"=>$id,
        "title"=>$title,
        "residence"=>$residence[0],
        "startdate"=>$startdate,
        "enddate"=>$enddate,
        "starttime"=>$starttime,
        "endtime"=>$endtime,
        "description"=>$description,
        "firstname"=>$firstname,
        "lastname"=>$lastname,
        "housing"=>$housing,
        "housenr"=>$housenr

    );
    //dd($data);
    DB::table('tasks')->insert($data);
    return redirect('/todo');
```

[errorcode picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x711x.png)

Comment: @mohammad.kaab I'm struggling with this now

Answer (score 0):

According to your above query the

$firsname should not a single vaule. It must be array or object. So
please try using following code to access firstname.

You are also getting error for accessing object as string value.

> ```
>   "firstname"=>$firstname->firstname,  //If firstname is object
> ```
>
> OR
>
> ```
> "firstname"=>$firstname['firstname'],  //If firstname is array
> ```